# Upper bound $\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\alpha(x(x+\beta+1))^2\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for an upper bound as tight as possible going to $0$ as $\alpha\to\infty$ of

$$\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\alpha(x(x+\beta+1))^2\right).$$

Comment: The method I gave you in your previous question (that you erased, why ?) works also here.

Comment: @Surb I'm sorry, I deleted it because I made an error in my analysis. Could you please recall your methode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $\beta >0$. Remark that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-a\big(x(x+\beta +1)\big)^2}\,\mathrm d x\leq \int_0^\infty e^{-a(\beta +1)^2x^2}\,\mathrm d x,$$ and use the fact that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm d x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}.$$